# Let's get critical: Jan 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Windows Phone Stack Exchange](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Home screen bumped down by nothing](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2585/home-screen-bumped-down-by-nothing)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Not all Google Calendars shown](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2684/not-all-google-calendars-shown)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How can I create a short cut to a directory on a Windows Phone device?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2595/how-can-i-create-a-short-cut-to-a-directory-on-a-windows-phone-device)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Tasks/Todo list for WP8](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2686/tasks-todo-list-for-wp8)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Is there any way to monitor data usage on Windows Phone 7.x?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2604/is-there-any-way-to-monitor-data-usage-on-windows-phone-7-x)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Windows Phone 8 slower with SDCARD in than without](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2638/windows-phone-8-slower-with-sdcard-in-than-without)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Unofficial tethering on Windows Phone](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2714/unofficial-tethering-on-windows-phone)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Any way to make everything smaller on my Nokia Lumia 1520?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2695/any-way-to-make-everything-smaller-on-my-nokia-lumina-1520)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Google error 80048888 while synchronizing GMAIL](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2652/google-error-80048888-while-synchronizing-gmail)

**Net Score: -5** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 6)

---

- [Unable to volume down songs in music player after GDR2 update](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2657/unable-to-volume-down-songs-in-music-player-after-gdr2-update)

**Net Score: -5** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

Answer (score 4):

Many people still have a thought that [windowsphone.stackexchange.com](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com) is for windows phone developers. The site should get an exposure that it's for users not for developers.

Comment: Maybe the site could be renamed to "Windows Phone Users" or something similar?

Answer (score 2):

I think we have a lot of great question but many regular users are not noob in the subject.

It can be bad since we end up not having low knowledge questions. I've started to ask some question I know the answer to make our knowledge base grows and looks like it worked and the community responds to that.

I think we have a problem with some question that were answered but the OP never got it. A lot of times the OP just abandon the question and maybe even the Q&A. Sometimes looks like they don't want wait a couple of minutes or hours.

I would love the see a custom icon/favicons for our Q&A. The default blue is getting old to me ;)

Answer (score 2):

The questions usually show up quite well placed in Google searches, but not so on Bing. Perhaps there is some optimization that could still be done in that regard?